# errorInfo()[2], unexpected '[' in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, pdo

This simple line

```
$prep = $this->pdo->prepare($sql) or common::error("PDO prepare error: ".$prep->errorInfo()[2]);
```

is working on PHP 5.5, but fails on PHP5.3 (even if the PHP documentation says that PDOStatement::errorInfo returns an array on php 5.1+) saying:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in ...

I use it many times in my application, and unfortunately I can't update the PHP version on this machine. Any workaround?

Comment: The problem is that "array dereferencing" wasn't introduced till PHP 5.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just break it up into two steps:

```
$error = $prep->errorInfo();
$error_msg = $error[2];

$prep = $this->pdo->prepare($sql) or common::error("PDO prepare error: ".$error_msg);
```

FYI, this is called Array Dereferencing and became available in PHP 5.4.